# Set as default content type using site script

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-script

I am adding a content type using site script to a library which is already having three content types. Now I want to make my custom content type as default one. Is it possible to make a content type as default using site script?

The code I am using for adding content type is below:

```
{
  "verb": "createSPList",
  "listName": "Project List",
  "templateType": 100,
  "subactions": [
    {
      "verb": "addContentType",
      "name": "CustomProject"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MS documentation it is not possible to make a content type as default for a list /library using site scripts , but it is possible with power shell commands.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Project Document will be default content type:

```
        {
          "verb": "addContentType",
          "name": "Project Document"
        },
        {
          "verb": "removeContentType",
          "name": "Document"
        }
```